# Apple search ads API put request 400 recieved python

Tags: python, httprequest, apple-search-ads

I am required to change some data in a campaign using the apple search ads API which I haven't used before. I have managed to generate a token and do a get request for the data but when I make a put request the response received is an response[400].
The code im using is as follows:

```
import jwt
import json
import requests
headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer{"access token",
'X-AP-Context': f'orgId={orgId}',
}
payload = {"dailyBudgetAmount":{"amount": "300"}}
payload = json.dumps(payload, indent=1)
requests.put('https://api.searchads.apple.com/api/v4/campaigns/campaignId',json_data = payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Error 400 may happen because the server is expecting a POST request while here it seems like you are sending a GET request

Comment: I intend on sending a put request how would i change this?

Comment: Usually you don't have the choice, it's part of the code server side to list the accepted types of requests